# Como insertar una nueva fila con datos en una hoja de Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Vengo buscando ayuda en un código que me esta complicando bastante ya que debo usar (al menos eso creo) el método *Range. Find*, el cuál no he logrado saber como funciona.

### Lo que requiero es un código con el cual se puedan introducir nuevas filas en blanco en una hoja de excel, está fila se debe introducir si se cumplén ciertas condiciones.

Tengo una hoja en excel que contienen unos *"Subcapitulos"* e *"Items"*, existe la posibilidad de que se deban crear nuevos *Items* y para eso el usuario tiene el siguiente formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código hasta ahora lee el dato del campo *"Inserte el Nombre del Subcapitulo"* y lo va buscar a la hoja *"BDusuario1"*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que sigue (y es la parte en la que necesito ayuda) es que una vez localizado el objeto de búsqueda la macro se debe:

1. Desplazarse 2 columnas a la izquierda y leer un código que allí se
   encuentra, almacenarlo en una variable y sumarle 1
2. Luego en otra variable se debe almacenar el código que se encuentra
   una fila abajo del anteriormente mencionado.
3. Luego se deben comparar ambas variables y si son iguales ambas
   variables se deben desplazar una fila hacia abajo y hacer la misma
   comparación; si son diferentes se debe crear una fila en blanco en
   la mitad de las 2 variables

**Nota:** Los códigos solo pueden llegar hasta que terminen en 99 por ejemplo `4011099`, si se llego a ese limite y no se encontró ningún espacio para agregar el nuevo ítem se debe mostrar un mensaje informándole.

Adjuntare una copia básica del archivo original, ya que no puedo enviar el original, pero espero que les sea suficiente para trabajar. Los campos importantes para esta macro son los que les encierro en azul y resalto en amarillo, el resto lo pueden ignorar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Archivo de Ejemplo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L_5vAtli3x_9oN1pjTpAxx0-0FcEslyE)

Espero haber logrado hacerme entender, si necesitan más información o mayor claridad en algo con gusto tratare de dárselas.

Esta es la parte del código en la que necesito ayuda, coloque comentarios de lo que debe hacer cada linea para lo que espero sea una mejor claridad.

```
    Cod = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2) 'Aca intento hacer una vez encontrado el dato de la variable "nomSubc" se mueva 2 filas a la izquierda y lea un código que allí se encuentra
    '''Cod = a.Cells(fila, "A").Value
'-------------------------

   For itm = 1 To 99
        Cod1 = ActiveCell.Value 'en esta parte lo que quiero es que una vez sea lea ese código se guarde en una variable
        Cod1 = Cod1 + 1         'y se le sume 1
'---------------------------

        Cod2 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) 'Aca lo que busco que se lea en código que esta de bajo del que se guardo en la variable "Cod1"
'---------------------------
            If Cod1 <> Cod2 Then            'En estás lineas se debe hacer una comparacion,
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert 'Si son diferentes se debe crear una fila vacia en la mitad de Cod1 y Cod2
                'ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0)    'Si Cod1 y Cod2 son iguales Cod1 debe pasar a leer Cod2 y Cod2 debe pasar a leer el código de abajo
            Else
        MsgBox "Error", vbExclamation
            End If
    Next itm
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Tienes razón en que es un poco larga, pero fue la mejor manera que encontré de tratar de expresar mi problema y también tienes razón en que excel no es una base de datos y ya he editado el titulo. Si deseas puedo tratar de ser más clara y precisa con respecto a mi problema y ver si tal vez me puedas ayudar.

Comment: Leeré atentamente la información que se encuentra en los enlaces, crees que sea mejor editar toda esa pregunta o hacer una nueva tomando en cuenta la información que me brindas

Comment: Ya he hecho los cambios, ¿que opinas?, ¿crees que ahora esta más claro que es lo que requiero?, ¿en el encabezado me falta ser más clara?

Comment: Te lo agradezco mucho, espero que con las nuevas ediciones alguien sea capaz de ayudarme, pero en verdad te lo agradezco me has ayudado bastante y seguro tendré esto en cuenta para próximas preguntas acá y en cualquier foro

Comment: no llames a esto foro.. no nos gusta ;).. fijate si mi respuesta te sirve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arme una pequeña planilla con números en su primera columna... y deje un hueco en el medio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, construi una funcion para que completara con una fila en blanco, donde deberia estar el 7.

```
Range("A1").Select
Dim num As Integer
num = ActiveCell.Value
Dim valido As Boolean
valido = True
While num < 100 And valido
    'si, la primera comparacion es con si mismo
    If (num <> ActiveCell.Value) Then
        'encontramos la fila diferente, tenemos que agregar una arriba de esta
        valido = False
        Range(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Else
        num = num + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Wend
If (valido) Then
    'aca sacamos el mensaje que no se pudo agregar
    MsgBox ("no se puede agregar")
End If
```

En el codigo, vamos a buscar A1, nos quedamos con ese numero, y recorremos hacia abajo, buscando donde falta alguno. El while corta cuando encuentre el hueco, o llegue a 100, lo que ocurra primero.

Si llego a 100, entonces mando el mensaje, para eso utilizo la variable booleana.

Creo que con esto puedes adaptar tu codigo para que funcione.

Comment: La verdad me está costando integrar el código que me proporcionas con el mio, ya que antes del código que adjunte hay otra pequeña parte (que consiste en la declaración de variables y la búsqueda del campo "Inserte el Nombre del Subcapitulo" dentro de la hoja [Una especie de BuscarV ]) y algo que tal vez no aclare muy bien es que los códigos no van del 1 al 99, son números de 7 dígitos pero cuando los 2 últimos dígitos llegan al 99 es cuando se detiene la macro y se envía la notificación de que no se pudo agregar la fila, si ves en la imagen en la Columna "A" veras los códigos de los que hablo

Comment: No aceptes una respuesta, hasta tanto no tengas una respuesta que te sirva. Lo que escribi es solo la logica que tenes que aplicar. Todo lo que viene antes, tiene que llegarle servido a esta funcion.. fijate que va y empieza en la primer columna, pero podria ir a empezar en cualquiera. Y lo de los 7 digitos, no varia ya que podrias ir construyendo el numero a medida que lo necesites... no tengo tu ejemplo particular (y no puedo bajarlo) como para probarlo. mas alla, esto es lo que querias?

Comment: Basicamente, arregle la funcion que no te funcionaba. Todo lo otro que pasa, es tema de otra pregunta.

Comment: Si, esto es lo que necesito. Ahora lo que haré es adaptar mi código con lo que me has dado y en verdad te lo agradezco mucho, llevaba muchos días atrapada acá. Por último me podrías explicar a que te refieres con que el numero lo puedo ir construyendo a medida que lo necesite

Comment: puedes usar como base el que viene.. y saber que va a terminar en algo asi como los 5 primeros digitos mas 100.. y ese ser tu final... a eso me refiero... no es necesario saber el numero, se puede calcular...

Comment: La función "Mid" me podría servir?, la usaría para sacar los 3 últimos dígitos de la celda activa y guardarlos en una variable, para acto seguido usar es variable para hacer la condición de si es menor a 100

Comment: totalmente.. mid, dividir por 100 y quedarte con el resto.. tienes varias formas de hacerlo...

Comment: Perfecto, me pondré a trabajar en la adaptación e integración de la lógica que me has dado, si me veo en problemas recurriré de nuevo a esta pagina con una nueva pregunta, saludos y muchas gracias

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, primero te quería agradecer ya que gracias a ti logre hacer lo que necesitaba y ya se insertan la filas vacías tal y como se necesitaba. Pero surgió una nueva necesidad (O requerimiento) con ese código, tal vez esté siendo inoportuna o molesta, pero crees que si reformulo la pregunta o hago una nueva me podrías ayudar nuevamente?.

Comment: Hace una nueva pregunta. Pone una referencia a esta si es necesario. Que bueno que funciono.