# ¿Cómo puedo insertar datos de un formulario a una fila vacía?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

En mi pregunta anterior solicite ayuda para insertar filas en blanco en una hoja de Excel, pero ahora necesito que se haga un paso adicional el cuál es introducir datos de un formulario a esa fila y asignarle un código siguiendo el consecutivo. Más específicamente los pasos son:

1. En la columna "A" agregar el código de arriba + 1 (para poder seguir
   el orden del consecutivo)
2. En la Columna "C" se debe introducir el dato que fue ingresado el
   Textbox *"txtnitm"*
3. En la Columna "D" debe ir el dato introducido en el Textbox
   *"txtuitm"*

No mencione la columna "B" ya que esta debe quedar vacía. Adjuntare el código el cuál gracias a la ayuda en la pregunta anterior logre desarrollar y también el enlace a la pregunta anterior. Espero haber logrado transmitir lo que necesito de forma clara, agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda.

```
Private Sub cmdnins_Click()

Dim num As Integer
'num = ActiveCell.Value
Dim valido As Boolean
valido = True

If cbxnsubc.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "Primero debes seleccionar un Subcapitulo"
    Exit Sub
End If

nomSubc = cbxnsubc.Value

Set h = Sheets("BDusuario1")
    v = h.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    u = h.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set b = h.Range("C2:C" & u).Find(nomSubc, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    b.Select
    evn = b.value
    ubc = Mid(evn, 5, 3)
    num = ActiveCell.Value

While ubc < 100 And Valido
    'Aca se introduce la nueva fila
    If (num <> ActiveCell.Value) Then
        valido = False
        Range(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormarFromLeftOrAbove
    Else
        num = num + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Wend
If (valido) Then
    MsgBox ("No se pudo agregar")
End If        

End Sub
```

[Como insertar una nueva fila con datos en una hoja de Excel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179550/como-insertar-una-nueva-fila-con-datos-en-una-hoja-de-excel)

Comment: Logras obtener los datos del formulario? los tenes en alguna variable?

Comment: No los almaceno en ninguna variable, solamente están alojados en textbox (lamento la tardanza pero fue fin de semana y no me permiten llevarme archivos para trabajarlos desde casa)

Comment: OK. lo primero que hay que hacer es saber el nombre del form.. y despeus funciona como cualquier form en vb...

Comment: El form se llama "frmAgregar", y si, su funcionamiento es como cualquier form, o al menos no hay nada poco común

Comment: He decidido almacenar los datos en variables, haciendo a `nom = txtnitm` y a `unid = txtuitm`. Y para el código no estoy muy segura pero creo que para darle el código sería `Ncod = ActiveCell.Offset (-1, 0).Value + 1`

Comment: Si obtuviste los valores del form ya lo resolviste. De la misma forma que obtenes el valor de una celda, podes ponerle  un valor por codigo ;)

Comment: De hecho no se como enviar los datos, ya que esta fila se puede crear en cualquier parte de la hoja, así que no son celdas fijas a las que se enviarán los datos, lo único fijo son las columnas más no las filas. Este es el código que trate de usar pero me sale error
  `Ncod = ActiveCell.Offset (-1, 0).Value + 1
  h.Rows(v, "A").Value = Ncod
  h.Cells(u, "C").Value = unid`

Comment: error 1004 para ser mas precisa y sale en las lineas   
`h.Rows(v, "A").Value = Ncod
h.Cells(u, "C").Value = unid`

Comment: te fijaste como hace excel para poner el valor en una celda? pone grabar macro, selecciona una celda,escribi.. fijate que codigo genera.. y copiate a como lo hace ;)

Comment: Veo el código que me genera la grabadora de Macros, pero no veo el como implementarlo, ya que se usa la propiedad Range y Select, pero siempre a una celda por ejemplo "C16", "A120", etc, pero las filas que se van a crear se pueden generar en cualquier fila, así que la fila siempre va a ser variable ... Lamento si no estoy entendiendo lo que me tratas de enseñar y explicar, pero en verdad estoy muy perdida y confusa

Comment: Pero.. vos sabes que fila generaste, porque te paraste exactamente en la fila de abajo... o no?

Comment: No, la fila que queda señala o sobre la que quedo parada es la que se genera

Comment: Entonces sabes sobre que fila tenes que meter los datos. no estaria entendiendo el problema...

Comment: Que no se como enviar los datos, los guardo en una variable pero como los envió allí?, también debería guardar esa fila en una variable? algo como `Vr = ActiveCell.Address` o como como envió esos datos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para guardar un valor en una celda, basta con seleccionar la celda y luego pasarle el valor que queres guardar.

```
Range("A12").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "asda"
```

Si tus valores estan en variables, alcanza con hacer:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = mivariable
```

Y si los valores vienen de un form, alcanza con hacer

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = miform.mitextbox
```

Comment: Dios, no puedo creer que no lograba ver algo tan... básico o evidente.... jajaja me siento un poco tonta, tratabas de decir algo tan fácil y no lo entendí jajaja

Solo una pregunta, una vez se inserte el primer valor, si deseo moverme una celda a la derecha para insertar el siguiente valor me bastaría con agregar el `Offset(0, 1)` antes del Select, verdad?

Comment: Ejemplo de lo anterios: este es el código con el que inserto el primer valor `Ncod = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
Range(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Ncod` Si quiero correr uno a la derecha sería Range(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & ActiveCell.Row).Offset(0, 1).Select

O como lo haría?

Comment: exacto. igual que hacias en el proceso anterior para ir bajando de a uno..

Comment: Me sale el error 1004, Error del método Range de objeto Global

Comment: haciendo esto te movias de celda: ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

Comment: Que extraño, ese fue el código que use para tratar de desplazarme pero me salia el error mencionado, lo reescribí y ahora funciona bien..... en fin, en verdad te lo agradezco muchisimo, no se que hubiera hecho sin ti, y disculpa si en algún momento te moleste con tanta insistencia y mi tontera al no entender lo que tratabas de explicarme, en verdad gracias